# Not able to get response header after error in angular interceptor

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-http-interceptors

I want to get response header in `HttpInterceptor` in angular if error comes.

I have tried below code in my Interceptor but getting null as in console.

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler):
    Observable<HttpSentEvent | HttpHeaderResponse | HttpProgressEvent | HttpResponse<any> | HttpUserEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(this.addHeader(req, this.getAuthToken())).pipe(
        catchError(error => {
            console.log(error.headers.get('errorCode'));
            console.log(error.headers.get('message'));
            return throwError(error);
        })
    );
}
```

Below is the snap of response header from browser's network tab.

[image]

Comment: They're not in Access-Control-Expose-Headers.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks. After adding it to ` Access-Control-Expose-Headers` it works. Thank you so much.